# Perl regular expression - lines must contain ADFHKMPRTWCEGILNQSVY and nothing else

Tags: regex, string, perl

Can somebody help me - I need a regular expression that matches only lines containing the characters `ADFHKMPRTWCEGILNQSVY` and NOTHING else.

I need to loop through lines of text that look like this:

```
>gi|46450118|gb|AAS96767.1| femAB family protein [Desulfovibrio vulgaris str. Hildenborough]
MVDLSRKKTQALLPTDILFQTPYWAQVKTRLGMESHAFDIRSSGPWGDVLVLLRRFGRHRVAIVPQGPEV
APPHEDYGVYLESFSLALAEGLGPDVAFIRYDLPWVSPYADEMHDEGWNAFPEARLRELRMNMGTRHWNL
RKSFQDLTVASSLVVDITGEEAAVLERMKPKTRYNIGLARRKGVAVREVGRESLPQFHALYRQTAIRNGF
EPCSITHFSAMFHALCDGAGSTELLFLLATHGTDILAGCIVGLAGRTANFLYGASGNVKRNLMAPYLMHW
TAMCHARDRGCHDYEMGAVPPGHDPAHPFHGLYRFKTGFGGRVALRSGSWDYPLDHAAYRDFCNAESLYR
TDAAPGRTQ

>gi|46450117|gb|AAS96766.1| iron-sulfur protein CooF [Desulfovibrio vulgaris str. Hildenborough]
MNHEELFVIQAEAEKCRACRKCELACIASHNNLTIKEAAKKRTVFAPRVHVVKTDEVKMPVQCRQCKDAP
CARVCPTRALVQDDGVVTMRAQFCAACRLCIMACPYGAISLSFIGLPEEDEAGAMHGREVAVRCDLCSEW
RAREGKSSCACVEACPTKALHMVPLAEARGRHQ

>gi|46450116|gb|AAS96765.1| hydrogenase nickel insertion protein HypA [Desulfovibrio vulgaris str. Hildenborough]
MHEASIVAGIMRIVEEEAARHDVTRIARVRLRVGLLTGVEPRTLTACFELYSEGTVAEGASLDLETVPAL
GTCHACGATFDLHRRCFACPTCGNDDITLEGGRELTIAGLEVPQPEGATA

>gi|46450115|gb|AAS96764.1| carbon monoxide-induced hydrogenase CooH, putative [Desulfovibrio vulgaris str. Hildenborough]
MSTPDSTTQTWTLPVGPLHVALEEPMYFKLDVDGEIVRNVEITAGHVHRGMEALAMRRNLFQNIVLTERV
CSLCSNSHPFTYCMAVEHLAGIEVPARADHLRVVAEEIKRTASHLFNVAILAHIIGFKSLFMHVMEVREI
MQDIKETVYGNRMDLAANCIGGVKYDVDAELLAMLLAGLDKVERNAREIYRIYASDPMVTGRTTGIGVLP
PDEARRFGVVGPVARGSGLAVDVRRDVPYAAYPQLSFDVITEEGCDVRARALVRLREVFESISIIRQCVA
TLPEGAMTVIMPEIPAGQSVARSEAPRGELMYYLRTDGTDIPNRLKWRVPSYMNWDALGVMMRDANVADI
PLIVNSIDPCISCTER

>gi|46450114|gb|AAS96763.1| hydrogenase, CooU subunit, putative [Desulfovibrio vulgaris str. Hildenborough]
MPDNALTAPLATALDALAEAEGFTWTRDAHGNAYGWLRLAERDTLPEAARLLAEGGARLATVTAYDPVRE
PGVPRQEIAYHFDVHGTTLTVTVVLDPECPSVPSITPHFRNADWNEREFMEMYDIAVPGHPNPRRLFLDE
KLDAGIMNTIIPLSTMTNGASTQNLWERILAARPGDKA

>gi|46450113|gb|AAS96762.1| hydrogenase, CooX subunit, putative [Desulfovibrio vulgaris str. Hildenborough]
MFGFLKVLARNVLKGPSTDPFPFAEAHTPARFRGQVRLDPALCVGCAICHHVCAGGAINIAEREDGSGYD
FTVWHNTCALCGLCRHYCPTGAITLSNDWHNAHLQSQKYDWCERQFVPFMQCEGCGAHIRPLPPQLAARA
YGPGGFDFASFMRLCPSCRQLAAARADVHIPEASAMPAAPAGHADEPAIREGDATAVTVKGDETPATGVQ
Q
```

They all start with >, so I could just look for that. However, I want to make double sure that I get the right lines, so I also want a regexp that matches lines containing ADFHKMPRTWCEGILNQSVY and nothing else.

Cheers,

Stefan

Comment: Just to clarify - I don't mean the string ADFHKMPRTWCEGILNQSVY, but lines containing any of those characters and no other.

Comment: May we have a look at your actual code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to construct a regular expression that allows any of those characters any number of times between the start and the end of the line. Here is an example script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    if (/^[ADFHKMPRTWCEGILNQSVY]+$/) {
        print $_;
    }
}

__DATA__
>gi|46450118|gb|AAS96767.1| femAB family protein [Desulfovibrio vulgaris str. Hildenborough]
MVDLSRKKTQALLPTDILFQTPYWAQVKTRLGMESHAFDIRSSGPWGDVLVLLRRFGRHRVAIVPQGPEV
APPHEDYGVYLESFSLALAEGLGPDVAFIRYDLPWVSPYADEMHDEGWNAFPEARLRELRMNMGTRHWNL
RKSFQDLTVASSLVVDITGEEAAVLERMKPKTRYNIGLARRKGVAVREVGRESLPQFHALYRQTAIRNGF
EPCSITHFSAMFHALCDGAGSTELLFLLATHGTDILAGCIVGLAGRTANFLYGASGNVKRNLMAPYLMHW
TAMCHARDRGCHDYEMGAVPPGHDPAHPFHGLYRFKTGFGGRVALRSGSWDYPLDHAAYRDFCNAESLYR
TDAAPGRTQ
```

Output:

```
MVDLSRKKTQALLPTDILFQTPYWAQVKTRLGMESHAFDIRSSGPWGDVLVLLRRFGRHRVAIVPQGPEV
APPHEDYGVYLESFSLALAEGLGPDVAFIRYDLPWVSPYADEMHDEGWNAFPEARLRELRMNMGTRHWNL
RKSFQDLTVASSLVVDITGEEAAVLERMKPKTRYNIGLARRKGVAVREVGRESLPQFHALYRQTAIRNGF
EPCSITHFSAMFHALCDGAGSTELLFLLATHGTDILAGCIVGLAGRTANFLYGASGNVKRNLMAPYLMHW
TAMCHARDRGCHDYEMGAVPPGHDPAHPFHGLYRFKTGFGGRVALRSGSWDYPLDHAAYRDFCNAESLYR
TDAAPGRTQ
```

Deconstructing the regex, we have:

- `^` matches the start of the string
- `[ADFHKMPRTWCEGILNQSVY]` matches any of the characters in the square brackets
- `[ADFHKMPRTWCEGILNQSVY]+` means match 1 or more times
- `$` matches the end of the string

Answer (score 5):

Something like this

```
/^[ADFHKMPRTWCEGILNQSVY]+$/
```

Comment: @user3790338, then you should select his answer as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

while (<>)
{

    if (/[ADFHKMPRTWCEGILNQSVY]/ and !/[0-9a-z>:;+-,.]/)
    {
        chomp;

        for ($i = 0; $i < length($_); $i++)
        {

            if (substr($_,$i,1) eq "A")
            {
            $aminoacids{A}++;
            }
            elsif (substr($_,$i,1) eq "D")
            {
            $aminoacids{D}++;
            }
            elsif (substr($_,$i,1) eq "F")
            {
            $aminoacids{F}++;
            }
            elsif (substr($_,$i,1) eq "H")
            {
            $aminoacids{H}++;
            }
            elsif (substr($_,$i,1) eq "K")
            {
            $aminoacids{K}++;
            }
            elsif (substr($_,$i,1) eq "M")
            {
            $aminoacids{M}++;
            }
            elsif (substr($_,$i,1) eq "P")
            {
            $aminoacids{P}++;
            }
            elsif (substr($_,$i,1) eq "R")
            {
            $aminoacids{R}++;
            }
            elsif (substr($_,$i,1) eq "T")
            {
            $aminoacids{T}++;
            }
            elsif (substr($_,$i,1) eq "W")
            {
            $aminoacids{W}++;
            }
            elsif (substr($_,$i,1) eq "C")
            {
            $aminoacids{C}++;
            }
            elsif (substr($_,$i,1) eq "E")
            {
            $aminoacids{E}++;
            }
            elsif (substr($_,$i,1) eq "G")
            {
            $aminoacids{G}++;
            }
            elsif (substr($_,$i,1) eq "I")
            {
            $aminoacids{I}++;
            }
            elsif (substr($_,$i,1) eq "L")
            {
            $aminoacids{L}++;
            }
            elsif (substr($_,$i,1) eq "N")
            {
            $aminoacids{N}++;
            }
            elsif (substr($_,$i,1) eq "Q")
            {
            $aminoacids{Q}++;
            }
            elsif (substr($_,$i,1) eq "S")
            {
            $aminoacids{S}++;
            }
            elsif (substr($_,$i,1) eq "V")
            {
            $aminoacids{V}++;
            }
            elsif (substr($_,$i,1) eq "Y")
            {
            $aminoacids{Y}++;
            }
            else
            {
            print "BAD AMINO ACID  $i  ", substr($_,$i,1), "  ", $_, "\n";
            }
        }


    }


}

foreach $key (keys %aminoacids)
{
print "$key -> $aminoacids{$key}\n";
}
```